# Prove that $\sum_{1}^{\infty} a_{n} \lt \infty \rightarrow \sum_{1}^{\infty} \arcsin(a_{n}) \lt \infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let be $\{a_{n}\}$ a sequence of real number / $0\lt a_{n} \le 1 \; \forall n \in \Bbb N $. Prove that $\sum_{1}^{\infty} a_{n} \lt \infty \rightarrow \sum_{1}^{\infty} \arcsin(a_{n}) \lt \infty$

So, **what I did**:

$$\text{If} \; \sum_{1}^{\infty} a_{n} \lt \infty \; \rightarrow \lim_{x\to \infty} a_{n} = 0$$

So, by the Limit comparison test, which states that if $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}} \gt 0 \; \text{then} \sum_{1}^{\infty} a_{n} \lt \infty \iff \sum_{1}^{\infty} b_{n} \lt \infty$

Then, $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}} = \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{\arcsin(t)}{t} = \frac{d}{dt} \arcsin(t)|_{t=0}=1 \gt 0$.

So that would be it. I don´t know if it's done correctly. **I don't know why the hypothesis that  $0\lt a_{n} \le 1$**. This is actually a two-part exercise but I'll put the second part in another Question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: From $\sin x/x\sim 1$ as $x\rightarrow0$, you can see that $0<\arcsin(y)<cy$ for some $c>0$ and $0\leq y\leq 1$

Comment: Well, $\arcsin$ is defined on $[-1,1]$ (assuming we are working on $\mathbb{R}$), and so...

Comment: @Karl Hi Karl. I hope that you're doing well. I've sent you a couple of messages, but am unsure if you've received them. Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. And feel free to up vote an answer as you see fit of course. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a convergence criterion from  *Asymptotic  Analysis* for series with positive terms:

> If $\:a_n,b_n >0\:$ and  $a_n\sim_{n\to \infty} b_n$, then $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ converges (resp. diverges) if and only if  $\sum\limits _{n=0}^\infty b_n$ does.

Now here, as you observed, $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$, so $\:\arcsin a_n\sim_{n\to\infty}a_n$, and you can apply the above result.

Comment: I'm not seeing what I did wrong. Is it badly apply the limit comparison test the way I did it?

Comment: You didn't do anything wrong. It is more or less the same as what I propose. I just wanted to point out that using asymptotic analysis makes often proofs much shorter as you don't have to bother with unnecessary details.

Comment: Oh, ok. Sorry, I wasn't familiar with Asymptotic Analysis. It is really helpfull. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Defining the arcsine function as $\arcsin(x)=\int_0^x\frac1{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\,dt$, we have the following estimate for $a_n\in (0,1)$.

$$\begin{align}
|\arcsin(a_n)|&=\int_0^{a_n}\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx\\\\
&\le \frac{a_n}{\sqrt{1-a_n^2}}
\end{align}$$

Inasmuch as $a_n\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$, there exists a number $N$ such that for all $n>N$,  $\sqrt{1-a_n^2}>\frac12$.

Hence we assert that

$$\left|\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \arcsin(a_n)\right|\le 2\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty a_n<\infty$$

and the series of interest converges.

Comment: How you come to $\int_0^{a_n}\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx \le \frac{a_n}{\sqrt{1-a_n^2}}$ ?

Comment: @karl Note that for $a_n \in (0,1)$ we have $\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}<\frac1{\sqrt{1-a_n^2}}$

Comment: Sorry, still can't see it. Is there a property that you are applying? The rest of the answer is clear to me.

Comment: If $0<x\le a_n<1$, then $$0<x^2\le a_n^2\implies -x^2\ge -a_n^2\implies 1-x^2\ge 1-a_n^2\implies \sqrt{1-x^2}\ge \sqrt{1-a_n^2}\implies \frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\le \frac1{1-a_n^2}$$

Comment: @Karl Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really wanted to give you the best answer I could give you. ;-)

Comment: @Karl Hi Karl. I hope that you're doing well. I've sent you a couple of messages, but am unsure if you've received them. Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. And feel free to up vote an answer as you see fit of course. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\frac {\arcsin x-x} {x^{2}} \to 0$ as $x \to 0$ by L'Hospital's Rule (applied twice). Now use the fact that $\sum a_n <\infty$ implies $\sum a_n^{2}$ is also convergent.

Note that $\arcsin x$ is not defined for $x>1$. That is the reason for assuming that $a_n \leq 1$.

Comment: $\sum_n\dfrac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}$ is convergent but the sum of squares of its terms is not...

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Read the question correctly. It is given that $a_n \geq 0$.

Comment: Fair; I did miss that in the original question (probably because the condition isn't actually necessary; the result is true even without requiring $a_n\gt 0$, as long as we keep $-1\leq a_n \leq 1$ to make sure that $\arcsin(a_n)$ is well-defined.)